# Add object property in Vue 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating a simple shopping cart in which the user could add a quantity of the item they wish to add to their cart.

I have an array of tickets that I am passing into my page:

```
"tickets":[  
  {  
     "id":1,
     "title":"cheap",
     "price":"5.00"
  },
  {  
     "id":2,
     "title":"VIP",
     "price":"19.99",

  },
  {  
     "id":3,
     "title":"General",
     "price":"9.99"
  }
]
```

The general idea is that I would provide an input for users to indicate the quantity they want to purchase.  Upon change of the input a new "quantity" property would be added to the ticket object.

I have read the docs and realize that:

> Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the Vue.set(object, key, value) method

I generally understand how that should work, but I don't know how to actually do it inside of my component.

Specifically, how do I pass both the correct ticket object and the value of the input to a method?

In my template I Loop through tickets:

```
<tr v-for="ticket in tickets">
  <td>{{ticket.title}}</td><td><input id="quantity" @change="update"</td>  
</tr>
```

To get the element value, I can do this:

```
//script
update: function(e){
 quantity = e.target.value
}
```

But if I do this, how do I access the specific ticket object?

Alternatively, I coould pass the ticket instance:

```
<td>{{ticket.title}}</td><td><input id="quantity" @change="update(ticket)"></td> 

 //script
update: function(ticket){
 //access ticket object...
}
```

But if I do this, how do I access the quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use special `$event` variable

```
<tr v-for="ticket in tickets">
  <td>{{ticket.title}}</td><td><input id="quantity" @change="update(ticket, $event)"</td>  
</tr>
```

Documentation link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers